# Outlook Save Item Variable Path

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the following code to automatically save sent items to a folder:

```
Sub SaveACopy(Item As Object)
Const olMsg As Long = 3

Dim m As MailItem
Dim savePath As String

If TypeName(Item) <> "MailItem" Then Exit Sub

Set m = Item

savePath = "S:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Correspondence\"
savePath = savePath & m.To & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd-hhNNss")
savePath = savePath & ".msg"


m.SaveAs savePath, olMsg
```

How do I dynamically change the path so that mail is stored in a folder relevant to the recipient? Effectively, a folder would be created if its the first email to the user, or if the folder exists, it will be stored in there. In my head the save path looks like this:

```
savePath = "S:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Correspondence\m.to\"
```

But clearly, that does not work.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
savePath = "S:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Correspondence\" & m.to & "\"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this seems to generate a compile error

Comment: Could it be that the `m.To` contains an `@` sign and that such a character is not allowed in a path? Maybe it works if you alter your answer to `savePath = "S:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Correspondence\" & Replace(m.to, "@", "To") & "\"`?